# Angularjs How uri components are encoded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uriencoding

I was expecting AngularJS to encode query string parameters using the standard javascript function `encodeURIComponent`. According to the following test it is not the case:

```
describe('$http', function () {
 it('encodes uri components correctly', inject(function($http, $httpBackend) {
   var data = 'Hello from http://example.com';
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/process?data=' + encodeURIComponent(data));
   $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/process', params: { data: data } });
   $httpBackend.flush();
 }));
});
```

The test fails with the following error:

> $http encodes uri components correctly
>   Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/process?data=Hello+from+http:%2F%2Fexample.com
>   Expected GET /api/process?data=Hello%20from%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com

To sum up:

- Expected encoding: `Hello%20from%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`
- Actual encoding: `Hello+from+http:%2F%2Fexample.com`

What uri component (aka query string parameters) encoding method should I expect with AngularJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular (at least 1.3) doesn't only use encodeURIComponent and changes some replacements (like " " to "+").

this is the commit explaining why : 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9e30baad3feafc82fb2f2011fd3f21909f4ba29e

And here's what you can see in 1.3 sources :

```
/**
 * This method is intended for encoding *key* or *value* parts of query component. We need a custom
 * method because encodeURIComponent is too aggressive and encodes stuff that doesn't have to be
 * encoded per http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986:
 *    query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
 *    pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
 *    unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
 *    pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
 *    sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
 *                     / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
 */
function encodeUriQuery(val, pctEncodeSpaces) {
  return encodeURIComponent(val).
             replace(/%40/gi, '@').
             replace(/%3A/gi, ':').
             replace(/%24/g, '$').
             replace(/%2C/gi, ',').
             replace(/%3B/gi, ';').
             replace(/%20/g, (pctEncodeSpaces ? '%20' : '+'));
}
```

note that `pctEncodeSpaces` is hardcoded to `true`;

Here's what you can do to decode URI parameters

```
decodeURIComponent(val.
             replace('@', '%40').
             replace(':', '%3A').
             replace('$', '%24').
             replace(',', '%2C').
             replace(';', '%3B').
             replace('+', '%20'));
```

Comment: Can we access it somehow like angular.encodeUriQuery or something?

Answer (score 4):

In my humble opinion AngularJS is wrongly encoding in the same way URI path segments AND URI query parameters. To me this is a bug and I actually issued a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12201) for fixing it.

The test I introduce in the pull request actually confirms this bug (tested it with both AngularJS `1.3.*` and current `master`).

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12201

Answer (score -3):

It appears that when you are passing the parameters pre encoding. You encode the URL but after you pass a non-encoded url through the JSON data parameter. Maybe this alteration to your code will work.

```
describe('$http', function () {
 it('encodes uri components correctly', inject(function($http, $httpBackend) {
   var data =  encodeURIComponent('Hello from http://example.com');
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/process?data=' + encodeURIComponent(data));
   $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/process', params: { data: data } });
   $httpBackend.flush();
 }));
});
```

Also, After taking only the URL encoding piece and placing it inside a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/eNtgL/1/

It appears to be working correctly, you may want to investigate external factors causing the issue with your URL. There are also several other options described here in this

[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi - I am passing the parameter pre encoding because I am expecting AngularJS (the js framework I am using here) to do it for me. And it does. But in a way I am not expecting it. It doesn't do the encoding through the `encodeURIComponent` function. My question is specific to AngularJS.

Comment: Please try pre-encoding per my code above. Make the following change to this line.  var data = encodeURIComponent('Hello from http://example.com');

Comment: I cannot encode myself the data I pass to the framework for server communication. According to the documentation the `$http` function should do it transparently. And it actually does it correclty. My problem is mainly about testing, like in the jasmine test I included in my question. Pre-encoding in my code is not acceptable.