# How to send dot character as a parameter from angularjs $http

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to send `.` (dot) as a string to the following aspi call in Nodejs.
I am using Angularjs `$http` object.

I can see that the call is being made with the dot (.) character that I have entered in the search box.

https://localhost:3003/posts/search/.

However, when I see the ajax call through google developer tool, it is making a call as:

https://localhost:3003/posts/search/

How can I pass a dot character?

code is:

return

```
$http.get('https://localhost:3003/posts/search/.').then(getPostCompleted).catch(function (message) {
                handleException(message);
            });
```

I don't think I have to btoa or atob on this?

Thanks
Am

Answer (score 1):

You should use get params using something like :

```
https://localhost:3003/posts/search?req=.
```

and get the `req` params in your code. I know it's not the route your wanted but i think  that the dot is a special character that coulnd't be use in the route because it is use for the domain

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass a dot character?

String in URLs mush be [url-encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Raw javascript has a [function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) that does this, but angular.js $http service has [special behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542465/angularjs-how-uri-components-are-encoded) for this.

EDIT :

> I can see that the call is being made with the dot (.) character that I have entered in the search box.
>
> https://localhost:3003/posts/search/.
>
> However, when I see the ajax call through google developer tool, it is making a call as:
>
> https://localhost:3003/posts/search/

Chrome must be stripping dots without extension by default. A regex parsing it somewhere maybe.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856693/a-url-resource-that-is-a-dot-2e) about using a dot.

If you want to use GET then you could pass the parameter as a query string i.e

```
$http.get('https://localhost:3003/posts/search?string=.')
.then(getPostCompleted).catch(function (message) {
    handleException(message);
});
```

Otherwise you can use POST and add the parameter to the body

```
$http.post('https://localhost:3003/posts/search', {string: '.'})
.then(getPostCompleted).catch(function (message) {
    handleException(message);
});
```

Comment: It will not go any further as my route will match to the wrong one - I have one with /posts/:category and another one is /posts/search/:term - thus when I specify as ?term=. it will go to the first one and it is not the solution. I like the post part though which I was thinking to not to use however not a bad idea considering the post is XSS attack safe too. +1