# "dot" in query string parameter - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url, query-string

I'm trying to use dot (.) in query string parameter but its not working.

This URL is working fine:

http://localhost:9000/search-result?majTFMin=0&majTFMax=100&majDOMCFMin=0&majDOMCFMax=100&majRefDomainsMin=0&majRefDomainsMax=100&majRefIPsMin=0&majRefIPsMax=100&majRefDomainsEDUMin=0&majRefDomainsEDUMax=100&majRefDomainsGOVMin=0&majRefDomainsGOVMax=100&selectedTLDs=com

But not this one as it contains a dot in a parameter:

http://localhost:9000/search-result?majTFMin=0&majTFMax=100&majDOMCFMin=0&majDOMCFMax=100&majRefDomainsMin=0&majRefDomainsMax=100&majRefIPsMin=0&majRefIPsMax=100&majRefDomainsEDUMin=0&majRefDomainsEDUMax=100&majRefDomainsGOVMin=0&majRefDomainsGOVMax=100&selectedTLDs=co.uk

When I'm trying to open above URL (with dot), it just prints:

Cannot GET /search-result?majTFMin=0&majTFMax=100&majDOMCFMin=0&majDOMCFMax=100&majRefDomainsMin=0&majRefDomainsMax=100&majRefIPsMin=0&majRefIPsMax=100&majRefDomainsEDUMin=0&majRefDomainsEDUMax=100&majRefDomainsGOVMin=0&majRefDomainsGOVMax=100&selectedTLDs=co.uk

And **nothing else**, not even any HTML tags(has checked that in view source)

I have read lots of posts which says that . can be used in query string without encoding, but I don't understand why its not working here. I think it has some issue with AngularJS.

I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for state change and passed value to controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send dot character as a parameter from angularjs $http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095288/how-to-send-dot-character-as-a-parameter-from-angularjs-http)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) on your server (like [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) does), the URLs with a dot are not rewritten by default.

[connect-history-api-fallback code](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/blob/e5bc77c5b1e3c9d07647764675971d262e773ac9/lib/index.js#L59-l67)

```
if (parsedUrl.pathname.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
  logger(
    'Not rewriting',
    req.method,
    req.url,
    'because the path includes a dot (.) character.'
  );
  return next();
}
```

Starting with `connect-history-api-fallback` version **1.2.0** the [URLs with dots are allowed](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/commit/7dbc0bddd37eaa21fa71f4167939f59dc14367c9) and you can solve [this problem](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/issues/5) by using a a [rewrite roule](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#rewrites)

**Example**

If your URL with dot is `/search-result` and you angular app lives in the `index.html` page you can add a rewrite rule to the connect-history-api-fallback like this

```
rewrites: [
  {
    from: /^\/search-result/,
    to: 'index.html'
    }
  }
]
```