# angular2 & lite server dot in url leads to 404 not found

Tags: url, angular, http-status-code-404, lite-server

I'm using Angular2 Beta 14 and calling a URL with a "dot" in it leads to a 404 not found error from the lite server which is 2.2.0.

This is the URL I'm calling:

```
http://localhost:3000/confirmuser/token/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjYsInVzZXJOYW1lIjoiYXNkZmFzQGNlZC5saSJ9.PMzNWp8mbUKbSAiOqhOqjhZUYNejXY3pIQueBkc8_2E
```

The router path in app.component.ts looks like this:

```
{path: '/confirmuser/token/:token', name: 'ConfirmUser', component: ConfirmUserComponent}
```

The Chrome console shows this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Ant the Lite Server:

```
[1] 16.04.13 15:57:13 404 GET /confirmuser/token/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjYsInVzZXJOYW1lIjoiYXNkZmFzQGNlZC5saSJ9.PMzNWp8mbUKbSAiOqhOqjhZUYNejXY3pIQueBkc8_2E
```

When ever I call the url without a "dot", the page gets loaded correctly.

My aim here is, to confirm a user sign up. He receives an email with an URL he has to confirm. Using a JWT in this (and other cases) is habit I've been using.

Now I doubt this is an Angular issue, I believe this is a lite server issue.

Anyone experience with this?
Thanks

Comment: How did you resolve this? I'm going through the same issue. Was it a config you plopped in at your project root to overwrite default lite-server settings? I basically want to accept the dot coming so it drops to my correct route.

Comment: Hey @marketers yes I answered it my self below. I did not define the token as a parameter but rather retrieved it by calling param.get. Probably there might be a light server config, but I did not dig into this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a suitable workaround for this issue.
Basically I'm getting rid of the path parameter ":token" and replacing it by a query parameter

In the app.component.ts the new path now looks like this:

```
{path: '/confirmuser', name: 'ConfirmUser', component: ConfirmUserComponent}
```

An the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/confirmuser?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjYsInVzZXJOYW1lIjoiYXNkZmFzQGNlZC5saSJ9.PMzNWp8mbUKbSAiOqhOqjhZUYNejXY3pIQueBkc8_2E
```

In the component that handles this request I can continue to call route params as I was used to. So nothing to change there:

```
constructor(params: RouteParams){
  this.token = params.get('token')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36283859/1465640@

But it can be summarized with *dots doesn't work in urls unless you do some work on the lite-server config*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack then you need to change the config to make it working.
Please make the change in webpack dev server config file

```
historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
```