# Cannot have period in route or param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, lite-server

I really need to have a period in either a parameter or a route but lite-server seems to object to this.

I have found several places referencing the issue and saying that it can be fixed with a rewrite rule but there are no complete examples that I can see that work.

For instance this answer: ["dot" in query string parameter - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542479/dot-in-query-string-parameter-angularjs/36283859#36283859)

The path that can have a dot in it is `/report;url=example.com`.

Based on above answer I editted bs-config.json to this:

```
{
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    },
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "from": "/^\/report/",
        "to": "index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I also tried putting rewrites a level higher but neither had any effect on anything.

If I use `navigate('report/', { url: 'value.with.dot' })` then I can use a period in the route or param and it works fine but I can't access it directly by typing in the url to browser.

I find lots of mentions on the internet about this being due to lite-server config but no straight forward example of what exactly to add to the lite-server config to fix it.

I am using Angular2.4 but i think this is problem specific to lite-server.

So essentially I need a rewrite rule to re-write the request to index.html but the way i have entered it has not worked.

Comment: How did you resolve this? I'm going through the same issue. Was it a config you plopped in at your project root to overwrite default lite-server settings? I basically want to accept the dot coming so it drops to my correct route.

Comment: I switched to latest version of Angular CLI which seems to have a rewrite rule in it as default.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just shield the dot, like this "example\.com"?

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate inside a quotes

```
navigate('report/', { url: "'value.with.dot'" ))
```

Comment: It works fine with navigate, I have no problems with navigate so I do not need to change anything with that.  The problem I have is accessing the url directly.  Lite server treats all paths with period as a file and other answers say that a rewrite rule must be made.

Comment: you need to change in the route definitions also

Comment: this is route definition `{ path: 'report', component: MyReportComponent }`  Did you look at other answer I linked?  I don't think you are understanding my problem.

Comment: I want to be able to use a period (this ---> . <----this) in a path I type into browser.