# Angular $http params encoding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I have an Angular 1.4 service that makes an `$http.get()` request to the MapQuest API. If I pass my API key as part of the url directly then it works however if I add it as part of the `params` field then it does not.

Working:

```
var url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=Gmjtd%7Cluub2d08nh%2C2s%3Do5-2u2gh4';

$http.get(url);

// Key actually sent
Gmjtd%7Cluub2d08nh%2C2s%3Do5-2u2gh4
```

Not working:

```
var url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address';

$http.get(url, { 
  params: { 
    key: 'Gmjtd%7Cluub2d08nh%2C2s%3Do5-2u2gh4'
  }
});

// Key actually sent
 Gmjtd%257Cluub2d08nh%252C2s%253Do5-su2gh4
```

Not working either:

```
var url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address';

$http.get(url, { 
  params: { 
    key: encodeURIComponent('Gmjtd%7Cluub2d08nh%2C2s%3Do5-2u2gh4');
  }
});

// Key actually sent
Gmjtd%25257Cluub2d08nh%25252C2s%25253Do5-2u2gh4
```

It appears that passing the key in the `params` field causes it to undergo some kind of encoding process which renders it invalid.

How can I maintain the original key when using the `params` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does indeed [encode params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542465/angularjs-how-uri-components-are-encoded). You should call `decodeURIComponent` since the key is already encoded.

```
$http.get(url, { 
  params: { 
    key: decodeURIComponent('Gmjtd%7Cluub2d08nh%2C2s%3Do5-2u2gh4');
  }
});
```